# Cannot clone from local gitlab server via ssh url

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-clone

[image: SSH URL]

I failed to clone from my local gitlab server 
by SSH URL which I copied from browser (Please see 1st picture)

but after I have changed SSH URL from domain name to git server IP instead

(Please see below picture)

[image: Git Bash]

That' s OK

Additionally :  connect to local git server via vpn connection
[image: Vpn client]

Comment: Do you have SSH set up on your local server?

Comment: It says "could not resolve hostname". That error seems pretty clear. The hostname you're using doesn't exist in dns or other hosts database. You have some local infrastructure problems to work out.

Comment: The same happens in my job gitlab repo, the solution? no idea, only to clone the repo i change to clone by https instead of ssh and it works